# Issues executing a MYSQL query (if a condition is met)

Tags: mysql

I run into a connection issue while attempting to run the following query:

```
"SELECT box_id, longestDimension from box where longestDimension != '' AND box_id == 'Box11'"
```

It was working fine with only this

```
"SELECT box_id, longestDimension from box where longestDimension != ''"
```

So I am guessing the issue is this

```
box_id == 'Box11'
```

This code is being run through nodeJs

Comment: Use only one `=` sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course John, operator == in mysql does not exist

```
"SELECT box_id, longestDimension from box where longestDimension != '' AND box_id = 'Box11'"
```

Must be like this

Comment: As a note, the `:=` operator as the assignment operator (which is typically `=` in other languages)